# Bloc Library Null

Tags: flutter, dart

In appbar I am trying to show profile icon after logged. When app start, appbar show profile icon, but at the same time in debug console give me an error 'A build function returned null'. When open profile page and return back, still the same error 'returned null' How to solve it?

```
class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => AuthBloc(
                  authService: AuthService())
                ..add(
                  AppStart(),
                ),
            ),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

homepage:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>( 
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is Authenticated) {
                return profileIcon(context);
              } else if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
                return logIn(context);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

bloc

```
@override
 AuthState get initialState => AuthState();
@override
Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
  if (event is AppStart) {
    try {
      final user = await AuthService.getCurrentUser();
      yield Authenticated(user: user);
    } catch (e) {
      yield UnAuthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

icon:

```
Widget profileIcon(context) {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      FlatButton.icon(
        icon: Icon(),
        label: Text(
          'Profile',
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfile()));
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

state:

```
class Authenticated extends AuthState {
  final FirebaseUser user;

  Authenticated({this.user});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [user];
}

class UnAuthenticated extends AuthState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Comment: Please share your bloc state class

Comment: added state class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure but my guess is you have another state for your `initialState` which is not handled in the `BlocBuilder`. Even though you add `AppStart event` right after providing `AuthBloc` which will end up with either `Authenticated` or `UnAuthenticated` state, you still need to put another `else` for your `initialState`. Even if it's not the case, try to add an else statement

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>( 
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is Authenticated) {
                return profileIcon(context);
              } else if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
                return logIn(context);
              } else {
                return Container();
              } 
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: I added else statement and it solved, but when open profile page and return back, bloc return Container. Why return container?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's either your AppStart event isn't emitted or your try catch doesn't actually yield either Authenticated or UnAuthenticated